# Problems configuring symfony 3.2

Tags: xampp, composer-php, symfony-3.1

I have xampp and installed symfony 3.2 in that folder using composer with cygwin. When i go to http://localhost/symfony3/web/config.php recommends me to:

1) intl extension should be available:
    Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

2) a PHP accelerator should be installed
    Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).
    realpath_cache_size should be at least 5M in php.ini

3) Setting "realpath_cache_size" to e.g. "5242880" or "5M" in php.ini* may improve performance on Windows significantly in some cases.

I have tried almost everything to solve this but i cant fix it. In number 3 I wrote 5M in that line and saved it but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `$xampp\php\php.ini`
2. On Line 340, copy and paste this:

   ```
   realpath_cache_size = 5242880k
   ```
3. Don't forget quit `;`

Answer (score 0):

**1)** realpath_cache_size relies on actual RAM, so my first step would be too check how much RAM your system has and close unnecessary apps.

**2)** realpath_cache_size is written in C:\xampp\php\php.ini so you may want to open that up and verify the number here.